# Capture user-set textarea size in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'd like to ask you advice about a textarea "problem". I like the user-resizable feature of the FF, and actually what I'm trying to achieve is if I submit something with a POST form, then after a page refresh the textarea will be the same size what the user dragged.

This doesn't seem to work with standard JS or PHP as during submit only the default, original rows and cols are transferred - not the virtual, what the user set. I assume this is a virtual value, managed by the browser.

Is there any way to capture the actual textarea cols&rows upon submitting? I don't need browser or much OS-compatibility, primarily a working solution for FF10.x under Windows and Linux would be perfect.

thanks in advance for any insights,
nm

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to jst make the form transfer its data over AJAX instead? Then no need to resize of the textarea just empty it instead

Comment: hi Sammaye, thanks for the advice, but actually this is a small intranet application for a few users. The pages are already generated dynamically via JS&PHP, so it was easier to push into this cosmetic feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `width` and `height`, not `rows` and `cols`. Then you can get the textarea's `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` and save them, then auto-size to that the next time the textarea appears.

Side-note: Chrome had resizable textareas before Firefox did.

Comment: hello Kolink, you're the man, thanks for the help. The offsetWidth and offsetHeight was the one I sought. Saving into a cookie, then read it after reload does the trick.

Comment: Personally I would suggest using `localStorage` for this. Since textarea resizing is only supported in browsers that already support Storage, it's safe to use.